# Run a function on each element in a dataframe column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-comparison

This one is a little tricky for me.

Dataframe:

```
parent           children
0   MAX          [MAX, amx, akd]
1   Sam          ['Sam','sammy','samsam']
2   Larry        ['lar','lair','larrylamo']
```

I have a function where if i pass in just a string, it will compare the two strings, and print out a number that describes how close the characters (in distance) are. Similar to the levenshtein equation.

How do i run this function on a dataframe though? I need to compare each record in the first column ('parent) to the corresponding list in the second column ('children')?

Currently, I can just run this and get this results:

```
>>> reference = 'larry'
>>> value_list = ['lar','lair','larrylamo']
>>> get_top_matches(reference,value_list)
>>> [('lar',0.91),('larrylamo',0.91),('lair',0.83)]
```

I'm trying to create a third column made of tuples for each row of the matches, like this:

```
parent           children                     func_results
0   MAX          [MAX, amx, akd]              [('MAX',1.0),('amx',0.89),('akd',0.56)]
1   Sam          ['Sam','sammy','samsam']     [('Sam',1.0),('sammy',0.91), ('samsam',0.88)]
2   Larry        ['lar','lair','larrylamo']   [('lar',0.91),('larrylamo',0.91), ('lair',0.83)]
```

I think the function should be able to work as is if I could figure out how to apply it in a for loop against the df.

---

here's are the functions:

```
import math
import re

def sort_token_alphabetically(word):
    token = re.split('[,. ]', word)
    sorted_token = sorted(token)
    return ' '.join(sorted_token)

def get_jaro_distance(first, second, winkler=True, winkler_ajustment=True,
                      scaling=0.1, sort_tokens=True):
    if sort_tokens:
        first = sort_token_alphabetically(first)
        second = sort_token_alphabetically(second)

    if not first or not second:
        raise JaroDistanceException(
            "Cannot calculate distance from NoneType ({0}, {1})".format(
                first.__class__.__name__,
                second.__class__.__name__))

    jaro = _score(first, second)
    cl = min(len(_get_prefix(first, second)), 4)

    if all([winkler, winkler_ajustment]):  # 0.1 as scaling factor
        return round((jaro + (scaling * cl * (1.0 - jaro))) * 100.0) / 100.0

    return jaro

def _score(first, second):
    shorter, longer = first.lower(), second.lower()

    if len(first) > len(second):
        longer, shorter = shorter, longer

    m1 = _get_matching_characters(shorter, longer)
    m2 = _get_matching_characters(longer, shorter)

    if len(m1) == 0 or len(m2) == 0:
        return 0.0

    return (float(len(m1)) / len(shorter) +
            float(len(m2)) / len(longer) +
            float(len(m1) - _transpositions(m1, m2)) / len(m1)) / 3.0

def _get_diff_index(first, second):
    if first == second:
        pass

    if not first or not second:
        return 0

    max_len = min(len(first), len(second))
    for i in range(0, max_len):
        if not first[i] == second[i]:
            return i

    return max_len

def _get_prefix(first, second):
    if not first or not second:
        return ""

    index = _get_diff_index(first, second)
    if index == -1:
        return first

    elif index == 0:
        return ""

    else:
        return first[0:index]

def _get_matching_characters(first, second):
    common = []
    limit = math.floor(min(len(first), len(second)) / 2)

    for i, l in enumerate(first):
        left, right = int(max(0, i - limit)), int(
            min(i + limit + 1, len(second)))
        if l in second[left:right]:
            common.append(l)
            second = second[0:second.index(l)] + '*' + second[
                                                       second.index(l) + 1:]

    return ''.join(common)

def _transpositions(first, second):
    return math.floor(
        len([(f, s) for f, s in zip(first, second) if not f == s]) / 2.0)

def get_top_matches(reference, value_list, max_results=None):
    scores = []
    if not max_results:
        max_results = len(value_list)
    for val in value_list:
        score_sorted = get_jaro_distance(reference, val)
        score_unsorted = get_jaro_distance(reference, val, sort_tokens=False)
        scores.append((val, max(score_sorted, score_unsorted)))
    scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return scores[:max_results]

class JaroDistanceException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(Exception, self).__init__(message)


reference = 'larry'
value_list = ['lar','lair','larrylamo']
get_top_matches(reference, value_list)
```

---

[image]

Comment: What is your function, what have you tried (with code) and what were your results? We ask that questions on this site include a [mcve] that can be run and tested against

Comment: What does you comparison function look like?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have add an executable version of the functions.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel Just added the functions to the question. refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your real dataset has exact 2 columns as your sample. Use `agg` on axis=1

```
df['func_results'] = df.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(*x), axis=1)


Out[366]:
  parent  ...                                    func_results
0    MAX  ...          [(MAX, 1.0), (amx, 0.89), (akd, 0.56)]
1    Sam  ...     [(Sam, 1.0), (sammy, 0.87), (samsam, 0.83)]
2  Larry  ...  [(lar, 0.87), (larrylamo, 0.85), (lair, 0.78)]

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Ok I tried this - and even though the elements in the lists aren't wrapped with " or ', this seems to just return a score for letters - and the same letter at that actually.

Comment: But yes - original df only has those two columns. Any ideas?!

Comment: could you share the output of this command `df.head(5).to_dict()`

Comment: Sure, See the image i just added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: ah, your `children_org_name_list` column contains string represent of list. I.e. it is list wrapping in string. It is not list of strings as you described. You need to convert each to a list of strings because you function expects a list of strings, not a string wrapping of list.

Comment: I'm actually having quite a tough time converting this column to a list of strings. do you know of a good way to do this?

Comment: @max: Try run this to convert to list of strings:  `df['children_org_name_list'] = df.children_org_name_list.str.strip('[]').str.split(',')`

Comment: I used this: ```df['children_org_name_list'] = df.children_org_name_list.apply(literal_eval)``` and it did the trick. Thanks so much Andy.

Comment: Hey Andy, not sure if you'll respond to this, but trying anyways - what if I had more columns in the dataframe, but still wanted to run a that function? not sure what (*x) does?

Comment: @max: `x` is each row of dataframe. `*x` unpacks each row into individual values. As you have 2 columns. `*x` unpacks each row into 2 values and passes them to `get_top_matches`. If your dataframe has more than 2 columns, but you only want pass 2 columns to `get_top_matches`, you need to slice 2 colums such as: `df[['col1', 'col2']].agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(*x), axis=1)` assuming `col1` and `col2` are 2 columns you want to pass values to `get_top_matches`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for that answer. One last question! `col2` in this example is converted to a column of lists; what if `col2` was just a regular column with one string per row? I've been trying all morning to get this `get_top_matches` function to run where `col2` has just one string per row, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: @max: convert `col2` into column of list:  `df['col2'] = df['col2'].agg(list)`. This command turns each cell of `col2` into a list of one string.

Comment: I made a post for it here: if you want to answer there if it's easier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638166/run-a-function-on-each-element-in-a-dataframe-column-of-lists-pt-2

Comment: @max: I posted an answer for that question